# MySQL JOIN two lookups

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables

**products**

```
id
code
description
category
subcategory
```

**product_categorys**

```
id
category_name
category_master
```

Data in **products** table

```
1, UK001, Description Text, 1, 2
```

Data in **product_category** table

```
1, Network Cable,  0
2, CAT6, 1
```

I want to lookup the products and return the category and subcategory i have reserached the best way to do this butt canot get my head around it, i have managed to return one lookup using the following.

```
SELECT products.product_code, products.description, product_category.category_name, product_category.category_name
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_category ON product_category.id = products.category AND product_category.ID = products.subcategory
ORDER BY description ASC
```

Which returns as expected

```
UK001, Description Text, Network Cables
```

I also want to return the subcategory, adding another join does not work and this is where i am stuck,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need two `join`s:

```
SELECT p.product_code, p.description, pc.category_name, pcs.category_name
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     product_category pc
     ON pc.id = p.category LEFT JOIN
     product_category pcs
     ON pcs.ID = p.subcategory
ORDER BY description ASC;
```

Note also the use of table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.